# Crosswalk integration in existing objective c iOS ionic project

Tags: ios, objective-c, ionic-framework, crosswalk

I am working on a project which is ionic and objective c based. I was able to add the XWalkView and crosswalk files. I tried to override Web view with XWALKVIEW, but it's not working. How do I know if crosswalk Web view is loaded.. And if it's working or not. I have seen sample project  and it's in swift.